# Use Scrapy to get information from a website that generates data using java script

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website using Scrapy, however the website URL doesn't change, the pages are loaded using java script.

This is how the site and URL look before I perform a search:
[image: image 1]

This is how the site and URL look after I perform a search:
[image: image 2]

How can I get the data from the site using Scrapy given these conditions?

Comment: you'll have to find out what requests are being made with javascript (maybe you can do them yourself also with scrapy), or you'll have to use something like selenium. We recommend [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash)

Comment: can I use the browser to find the request that are being made? @eLRuLL

Comment: that's what splash and selenium do, they emulate light browsers.

Comment: Add the url and your current working spider

Answer (score 0):

- You need analyse the website how to load the data.
  Maybe you can read the URL and HTTP header.
- Use some tools (like POSTman) to simulate the process about loading data.
- Use scrapy to implement the process.